# My are my UL lists (columns) for my dropdown menu in css written on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, dom, css-float

I have a dropdown menu in html/css with 2 nested columns.  When the top UL list is hovered, the second column being displayed on top of the first column.  The behavior is strange because each nested UL is created separately and directly displayed on top of each other.  Therefore the only 2nd nested UL is visible, with exception of the last the last LI of the first nested column. **These nested columns should be displayed besides each other**. They are currently floated to the left with tons of space to the right.

```
MY HTML:

<div id="headersection">
       <!-- Load the logo -->
       <div id="Logo">
          <img src="img/logo-name.png">
       </div>
       <div id="navMenuRgt">
          <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li> 
                        <b><a href="#">Brands</a></b>
                        <a href="#">Aumentum</a>
                        <a href="#">Checkpoint</a>
                        <a href="#">Ria and WG&L</a>
                        <a href="#">PPC</a>
                        <a href="#">Quickfinder</a>
                        <a href="#">Checkpoint Learning</a>
                        <a href="#">CS Professional Suite</a>
                        <a href="#">ONESOURCE</a>
                        <a href="#">All Products A - Z</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li> 
                        <b><a href="#">Solutions</a></b>
                        <a href="#">For Organizations</a>
                        <a href="#">Accounting Firms</a>
                        <a href="#">Corporations</a>
                        <a href="#">Financial Institutions</a>
                        <a href="#">Governments</a>
                        <a href="#">Law Firms</a>
                        <a href="#">TATCA</a>
                        <a href="#">BEPS</a>
                    </li> 
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">INSIGHTS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" style="width:175px">SUPPORT & LEARNING</a>
            </li>
      </div>
</div>

My CSS:

#headersection {text-align: center; height: 105px;}

#Logo {float: left; width: 50%; margin-top: 30px;}


#navMenuRgt {float: left; width: 50%; margin-top: 34px;}

#navMenuRgt ul li {text-align: left; list-style: none; position: relative; display: inline-table;} 

#navMenuRgt ul li a {text-decoration: none; width: 95px; display: block; color: #686868;}

#navMenuRgt ul ul {position: absolute; visibility: hidden; padding: 0px; }

#navMenuRgt ul li:hover ul {visibility: visible; background-color:             white; width: 650px; border: 1px solid black;
                               margin-left: -100px; }                      

#navMenuRgt ul li:hover ul li a {background-color: blue; width: 145px; color: orange; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are floating the whole `#navMenuRgt` object, not its contents.

Your CSS looks overly complex as well.  I would suggest simplifying the whole structure by adding `class`es to things.  `ul li` also selects `ul ul li` or `ul ul div span ul li` which is fine if thats what you intend, but is more confusing for future readers of your code (including yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    #navMenuRgt ul li:hover ul {
        visibility: visible;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #navMenuRgt ul li:hover ul:nth-of-type(2) {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: <total width of 1st ul>;
    }
```

What this does is moves the second `ul` by the first `ul`'s length. So you get side by side `ul`s.